# Fading images and non-looping slideshow in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a jquery slideshow for a website. I have 2 images: With the first image showing on the website, I would like the first image to fade out, slowly revealing the second image in place of the first. I don't want this to loop.

I would want the fading effect to begin around 4 seconds after opening webpage. I'd appreciate if someone can let me know what the correct coding would be for this. (I am not very familiar with jquery. Do I place the code in the head tag or body tag?).

This is the code I have, however the second image appears underneath the first, while I actually want it hidden, until it fades into place of the first. Also, it loops, which I don't want.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#banner img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('#banner :first-child').fadeOut(3000).delay(3500)
         .next('img').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500)
         .end().appendTo('#banner');}, 
      5000);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="banner"> 
  <img src="images/slide1.jpg" width="1024" height="300" alt="SS Image "/> 
  <img src="images/slide2.jpg" width="1024" height="300" alt="SS Image "/>
</div><!--end banner-->
```

**CSS:**

```
#container #banner { 
   border-bottom-width: 2px; 
   border-bottom-style: solid; 
   border-bottom-color: #F08840; 
   position: relative; 
   z-index:1; 
}
```

Comment: Where's the code you've tried so far? provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: @ZenithThis is the code I have, however the second image appears underneath the first, while I actually want it hidden, until it fades into place of the first. And it loops, which I don't want.

    $(document).ready(function() { 
       $('#banner img:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){
          $('#banner :first-child').fadeOut(3000).delay(3500)
             .next('img').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500)
             .end().appendTo('#banner');}, 
          5000);
    });

Comment: Have you got the HTML/CSS too? if we can have that, it will be solved quicker :)

Comment: ok, thanks, here they are: <div id="banner">
<img src="images/slide1.jpg" width="1024" height="300" alt="SS Image "/>
<img src="images/slide2.jpg" width="1024" height="300" alt="SS Image "/>

</div><!--end banner-->             #container #banner {
 border-bottom-width: 2px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-color: #F08840;
 position: relative;
 z-index:1;
}

Comment: This is what you wanted, right? - http://jsfiddle.net/XaSaN/

Comment: Very close, the only problem is that there is a delay from when the first image fades out until the next image shows up. For reference, the first image is a grayscale photo, and the second image is the same photo in color. I want the effect that the picture is slowly gaining color. Right now with your code, there is a small space with no photo seen at all.

Comment: One of these two is for sure what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/XaSaN/1/, or with the delayed first fade - http://jsfiddle.net/XaSaN/2/

Comment: yes, jsfiddle.net/XaSaN/2 is right! How would I show that this question is answered?

Comment: You can accept my answer by ticking it :) you'll see the tick underneath the score on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is the code I have, however the second image appears underneath
>   the first, while I actually want it hidden, until it fades into place
>   of the first.

This is caused by fading in the new image before the old one has fully faded out, causing it to begin underneath the first image. Use `fadeOut()`'s callback function to determine when the previous image has finished fading out, so you can fade in the next image.

> Also, it loops, which I don't want.

You need to replace `setInterval()` with `setTimeout()` if you only want it to occur once, in that case.

[**Here's a working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/XaSaN/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#banner img:gt(0)').hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#banner :first-child').delay('1500').fadeOut(function(){
          $(this).next('img').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).end().appendTo('#banner');
        });               
   },3000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need the second image appear above the first one http://jsfiddle.net/q7uvn/

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#banner img:gt(0)').hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
      var children = $('#banner').children();
      children.eq(1).fadeIn(1500); 
    },
    4000);
});
```